Riemiannian integrable function $f,g$ equals on a dense subset of $[a,b]$, show that $f=g$ almost everywhere

Riemiannian  integrable function $f,g$ equals on a dense subset of $[a,b]$, show that $f=g$ almost everywhere

By choose intermediate value on dense subset, we see $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$. Then some measure zero subset $Z$ exists such that $f,g$ are both continuous on $[a,b]-Z$.
The following $\forall\ x\in [a,b]-Z, f(x)=\lim_{d_n\to x}f(d_n)=\lim_{d_n\to x}g(d_n)=g(x)$ is false, where $d_n\in D$. Since we do not have $d_n\in [a,b]-Z$.
Now how to fix? Thank you .

The equalities still hold true if you take the limit with only points $d_n$ from the dense subset.

But $d_n$ need not be a continuity point for $f(x)= \lim f(d_n)$ to hold. All that matters is that $x$ is a continuity point

Hint: A function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $D_f$ has measure $0$ where $D_f=\{x\in A: f \text{ not continuous at } x\}$. Can you see how to proceed ?
